# Need to know which RAID type is better for my new NAS

Tags: nas

Got my WD my cloud NAS and need to set up the new RAID set up, which one is better and you guys recommend, RAID 0, or RAID 1? Need to make sure I won't lost my data again.

Thanks

Comment: "Need to make sure I won't lost my data again" – so you need a backup solution. [RAID is not a backup](https://serverfault.com/q/2888).

Comment: Please, see my updated answer and maybe remove the down vote, if it was You. I tried to actually inform You, there is much more to read up on, when You are serious about storage and offered some tips on backup as well.

Answer (score -1):

RAID-0 offers no protection against data loss.  RAID-0 is called striping and allows for the use off all disks in the RAID volume to be used for data storage.  The benefit of RAID-0 is speed and space over redundancy.

RAID-1 is mirroring.  It offers the highest redundancy, at the cost of losing the most storage.

Generally, if your NAS has 3 or more disks, you would want to use RAID-5, which requires a minimum of 3 disks, but loses less storage at the cost of redundancy.

Comment: Partiallly Disagree. If you have more then 2tb of disk and value your data (as the OP does), RAID 5 is not considered reliable because of the risk of failure of a second disk during a rebuild.

Answer (score -1):

**RAID 0** is called striping, because you divide your data into chunks that get written alternately between hard disks so if you write or read lots of data at once, you use all hard disks in parallel an are likely to achieve much higher performance. Of course, you are also likely to end up with just half the data, which isn't of much help since you will probably not be able to recover anything just from one half even when one stripe is about 64 kB big and could theoretically fit a largish text file e.g. Some forensics might be able to recover something but you will **not be happy**.

**RAID 1** also is a mirror between all hard disks. That means, that you have as many copies, as you have hard disks. It also means, that the write performance will depend on the slowest hard disk and the read performance can theoretically be performed in parallel on all hard disks (again when reading lots of data).

**TL;DR: Use RAID1 if you want better data security.**

You should still consider doing a backup on independent media regularly (ideally automating it). If you use Windows 10, it has the [file history](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17143/windows-10-back-up-your-files) feature which seems promising. WD might have some software for automatic backup as well, but I don't know how good it is. The open source tool [Areca Backup](http://www.areca-backup.org/) seems nice and simple. Remember, if you drop the NAS or it gets destroyed by over-voltage/ over-current during a storm, you have no data.

I wouldn't recommend using **RAID 5** at home for inexperienced users. I would jump on [RAID 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels) if you can afford using 4 hard disks and having just half the capacity. It is fast and dead simple from the controller point of view, because it doesn't calculate any parity. There have been many problems with RAID 5 in the past because it is just a lot more complex than RAID 10.

Also be sure to check the [SMART-values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) of the hard disks from time to time and run a scrub (a background job, that reads and rewrites all data to mitigate *bit rot*). In other words, storage is complex if done well. If you don't have much important data, I would strongly suggest using some cloud storage at least for (encrypted) backup archive it might be included with e.g. your Office 365 subscription without you knowing.